# Set field value using javascript in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm trying to set a field value using javaScript with the following code in Selenium + Java

```
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("document.getElementByXpath(\"//*[@tabindex='17']\").value = '05741180';");
```

But, I'm getting this exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: document.getElementsByXpath is not a function

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `getElementByXpath` is not a member of [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document)

Comment: So, how can I set value of a field using xpath in this case? Any Idea?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Within_an_HTML_Document looks like what you need

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enter **value** '05741180' in the field recognized by **xpath** '//*[@tabindex='17']', you can do that using javascript in the following way:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@tabindex='17']")), "05741180");
```

Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Comment: No, it did not work. When I execute it, the field is not filled and I get no error message :-(
Note: I'm executing it on chrome

Comment: Anyway, your message helped me to find this solution which worked just fine: 
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value = '05741180'", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@tabindex='17']")));