# selenium clear() command doesn't clear the element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been writing selenium scripts for a while in Java. I encountered a very weird issue today. Here is the issue:

I cleared a text field using webelement.clear() method, later while executing next command (click event), the text area I had previously cleared, is now populated with previously filled value.

Here is the code snippet:

```
mobileNumField.get(0).clear();
Thread.sleep(4500);
emailAddress.get(0).click();
emailAddress.get(0).clear();
Thread.sleep(4500);
emailAddress.get(0).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced a similar problem. The input field is cleared but the error message is not updated. It seems that some input fields work correctly only if you enter and delete a character:

```
element.sendKeys(text);
element.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE, Keys.BACK_SPACE);
```

Answer (score 42):

I don't know the exact reason for your element keeping its value, but you can try an alternative text clearance by sending 'Ctrl+A+Delete' key combination using sendKeys method of the element's object:

```
emailAddress.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a", Keys.DELETE));
```

Comment: As a complement to this solution: if the input field has text with special characters (for example, an input for a date that has '/') the sending of those keys must be break in two steps. First CONTROL + a, and then DELETE; otherwise, just a segment, until the first special character, of the text is deleted.

Comment: This solution does appear to work in the Python bindings too , but without the chords/actionchains sugar, and sending the DELETE key separately

Comment: For python, it's `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys; element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a"); element.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)`

Comment: looks like this does not work on mac since there we need `Keys.COMMAND` instead of `Keys.CONTROL`

Comment: this worked for me for a React app

Answer (score 17):

It's possible that the fields you're trying to fill has `autocomplete` attribute set to on. [[Reference]](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_autocomplete.asp)

If `clear()` works when the line executes then it's safe to say that this is not a webdriver specific issue.

It would help if you can show the html snippet of the page section you're working on.

Possible areas of debugging:

forcefully remove autocomplete attribute on page load using java script executor

turn off autocomplete setting on the driver level. I believe the solution would vary depending on the driver being used.

Good luck!

PS: Those `Thread.sleep`(s) are not advisable.

Comment: Though not a direct solution, this was a good explanation. Mine had autocomplete.

Comment: Best explanation, saved my day

Answer (score 9):

I solved it by adding a function to my BasePage to clear fields by a given WebElement.

```
 public void clearWebField(WebElement element){
    while(!element.getAttribute("value").equals("")){
        element.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
    }
}
```

You can also implement this method in the page that experiencing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Mac and the following code helps also

```
  public static void macCleanHack(WebElement element) {
        String inputText = element.getAttribute("value");
        if( inputText != null ) {
            for(int i=0; i<inputText.length();i++) {
                element.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with a text field that used an auto-complete plugin.  I had to explicitly clear the attribute value as well as do a SendKeys. I created an extension method to encapsulate the behaviour, hopefully the snippet below will help:

```
public static void SendKeysAutocomplete(this IWebElement element, string fieldValue)
{
   element.SendKeys(fieldValue);
   element.SetAttribute("value", fieldValue);
}

public static void SetAttribute(this IWebElement element, string attributeName, string attributeValue)
{
   var driver = WebDriverHelper.GetDriverFromScenarioContext();

   var executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
   executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);", element, attributeName, attributeValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear() didn't work for me either. This method I wrote is working for me as of 2024

```
public void ClearText(By element)
    {
        IWebElement elementToClear = driver.FindElement(element);
        elementToClear.Click();
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys("a").KeyUp(Keys.Control);
        actions.Perform();
        actions.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
        actions.Perform();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to clear the field and then `sendKeys()` the needed value

```
 while (!inputField.getAttribute("value").equals("")) {
        inputField.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
       }
        inputField.sendKeys("your_value");
```

Answer (score 0):

In some webforms clearing the field followed by `.sendKeys()` won't work because it keeps repopulating it with some autofill value (in my case it was due to an onfocus attribute function of an input element). Action chains didn't help, the only thing that worked for me was replacing the value attribute directly with javascript:

In Java:

```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementID').value='new value'");
```

In Python (nearly identical):

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('elementID').value='new value'")
```

For more on the Java version of this solution see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657777/set-field-value-using-javascript-in-selenium).

Answer (score 0):

Faced something similiar. I had required inputs field and when they were cleared, they would not update the verification. What I did was to create custom method that would check if the `element.Text` is empty and then it would send `Keys.LeftControl + "a" + Keys.Delete`

```
public static void Clear(WindowsElement element)
{
    if (element.Text != String.Empty)
        element.SendKeys(Keys.LeftControl + "a" + Keys.Delete);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @agleno I've reused your code and it was very helpful.
Also, it can be written like this, because I have coded it for cross OS/browser combinations.

For me it helped to send .clear() command twice. Hope it will be helpful to others:

```
public static Actions getBrowserActions() {
  return new Actions(driver);
}

/*
WebDriver has problem to clear input field when they contain 
'autocomplete' attribute. This method is workaround to clear these input 
fields. 
'role' == 'search' condition is workaround for input fields 
where 'autocomplete' will manifest with drop-down context-menu. Other 
input fields will be cleared with double '.clear()' call.

If your field with search autocomplete does not has 'role' attribute
please find some other attribute that will be different than classic 
input fields.
*/
public static void clearInputWebElement(final WebElement webElement) {
  if (webElement.getAttribute("role") != null) {
   if (webElement.getAttribute("role").equals("search")) {
    webElement.click();
    if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC) {
    // MacOS has Command key
      getBrowserActions()
        .keyDown(Keys.COMMAND)
        .sendKeys("A")
        .keyUp(Keys.COMMAND)
        .sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
        .build()
        .perform();
    } else {
    // Windows and Ubuntu has Control key
      getBrowserActions()
        .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
        .sendKeys("A")
        .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
        .sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
        .build()
        .perform();
    }
   }
  } else {
    webElement.clear();
    webElement.clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
javascriptExecutor js =(javascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executescript("arguments[0].click()",webElement);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.