# element.Clear() not working in 64-bit Selenium IEDriverServer.exe

Tags: c#, selenium, 32bit-64bit

I've encountered an interesting difference in behavior between the 32-bit and 64-bit Selenium `IEDriverServer.exe`.

When using the 32-bit driver and IE11, calling `element.Clear()` works but with the 64-bit driver and IE11 it doesn't (element doesn't get cleared).

```
var elementSelector = GetTableElementSelector(tableName, fieldName);
var element = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(elementSelector));
element.Clear();
```

Is this a known bug and is there a workaround?

Edit: I tried with a plain html input box and it works there even with 64-bit. The element where it doesn't work is a custom Angular component that has a date-time picker which shows a calendar so maybe the reason is related to [selenium clear() command doesn't clear the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677760/selenium-clear-command-doesnt-clear-the-element). It's still strange that it works for 32-bit, though, there is definitely some difference between x64 and x32 here.

Comment: 64-bit IE never worked properly for my tests too(when sending keys, it sent one key every 5 seconds or so, typing an email was a 3 minute task) i simply choose to always use the 32-bit version

Comment: I know this sounds weird, but for me it's the opposite - 32-bit IE and driver have slow SendKeys() while 64-bit IE/driver is fast. That's the reason I'm trying to migrate to 64-bit.