# Selenium Python - Login to application from Azure DevOps

Tags: python, azure-devops, dotenv, seleniumbase

MyScript is working totally fine in local with load_dontenv()

I am trying to pass username and password to my Python Test Script from Azure DevOps(Library->SecretFile) which is .env

content of .env (no filename give for .env .env named as .env)

```
USERNAME=user@username.com
PASSWORD=examplepassword
```

YAML file

```
script: | pip3 install python-dotenv displayName: 'Install dotenv'

task: DownloadSecureFile@1 inputs: secureFile: '.env'

script: | seleniumbase install chromedriver displayName: 'Install chromedriver'

script: | pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines displayName: 'Install Pytest' env: 
USERNAME_YAML: $(USERNAME) 

PASSWORD_YAML: $(PASSWORD)

script: | pytest example.py --browser=chrome -n=8 -v -s --slow displayName: 'Login Test'
```

python script

```
import requests

from seleniumbase import BaseCase

from datetime import datetime

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import os

class smoke(BaseCase):

#.env file info

username=os.getenv('USERNAME_YAML')

password=os.getenv('PASSWORD_YAML')
def leadverification(self):

    if self.env=="production":

        self.open("https://prd.cms.com")

    elif self.env=="develop":

        self.open("https://dev.cms.com")

    self.update_text(self.cmsemail,self.username)

    self.update_text(self.cmspword,self.password)

    self.click(self.cmsloginbtn)
```

Error Message in Azure Pipeline:

```
        selector - the selector of the text field
        text - the new text to type into the text field
        by - the type of selector to search by (Default: CSS Selector)
        timeout - how long to wait for the selector to be visible
        retry - if True, use JS if the Selenium text update fails
        """
        self.__check_scope()
        if not timeout:
            timeout = settings.LARGE_TIMEOUT
        if self.timeout_multiplier and timeout == settings.LARGE_TIMEOUT:
            timeout = self.__get_new_timeout(timeout)
        selector, by = self.__recalculate_selector(selector, by)
        if self.__is_shadow_selector(selector):
            self.__shadow_type(selector, text, timeout)
            return
        element = self.wait_for_element_visible(
            selector, by=by, timeout=timeout
        )
        self.__demo_mode_highlight_if_active(selector, by)
        if not self.demo_mode and not self.slow_mode:
            self.__scroll_to_element(element, selector, by)
        try:
            element.clear()  # May need https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691625
            backspaces = Keys.BACK_SPACE * 42  # Is the answer to everything
            element.send_keys(backspaces)  # In case autocomplete keeps text
        except (StaleElementReferenceException, ENI_Exception):
            self.wait_for_ready_state_complete()
            time.sleep(0.16)
            element = self.wait_for_element_visible(
                selector, by=by, timeout=timeout
            )
            try:
                element.clear()
            except Exception:
                pass  # Clearing the text field first might not be necessary
        except Exception:
            pass  # Clearing the text field first might not be necessary
        self.__demo_mode_pause_if_active(tiny=True)
        pre_action_url = self.driver.current_url
        if type(text) is int or type(text) is float:
            text = str(text)
        try:
>           if not text.endswith("\n"):
E           AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

That would have come from one of the following two lines if either `self.username` or `self.password` was None (The Python 'NoneType'):

```py
self.update_text(self.cmsemail,self.username)

self.update_text(self.cmspword,self.password)
```

And those lines would have an issue if one of these next lines wasn't pulling data:

```py
username=os.getenv('USERNAME_YAML')

password=os.getenv('PASSWORD_YAML')
```

So I would check to see that those lines return strings, or else you'll run into the issue you had.